# Modifying budget of an AdWord Campaign by using API

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I am implementing adword api version 201306 in one of my project. I am able to fetch the details of a campaign but unable to retrieve the budget details.

My goal is to access the budget details and modify them. I am using PHP library and request to all of you a piece of code written in php.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pramod

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and here is the way you need to go out - -

1. First you need to pass out the field 'BudgetId' in Campaign Service selector for CampaignStats.
2. Now you can use following code - - 
     $budgetService = $user->GetService('BudgetService', ADWORDS_VERSION);
     $bm = new Money('10000000');
     $campaign->budget->amount = $bm;
     $boperation = new BudgetOperation();
     $boperation->operand = $campaign->budget;
     $boperation->operator = 'SET';
     $budgetService->mutate($boperation);
   Yes, I agree that this help is very less. Do let me know if anyone face any issue OR need more help.

Regards,
Pramod

Comment: One more thing that I want to mention that any Idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the BudgetId was hard coded how would this be done? I have the budget id stored in a database of the campaign I want to change. I am using v201402. All I want to do is set budgetid of my campaign to 200.